# Change color of SVG in accordion control with wpf devexpress

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, svg, devexpress, glyph

I have an accordion control with svg's as button icon/glyph. It seems that visual studio/wpf or whatever would control the defaults the color to gray instead of svg's actual color. I am trying to change the color of the svg as well as the text content associated with it. I found a workaround by applying an image colorizer effect to the icon/glyph within the properties tab, but this seems to hide the blue highlight of the text content when user hovers over the button. So it seems that the colorizer would not be the actual answer to my issue. I hope I am explaining this well and hope someone can lead me in the correct direction. I have been searching for an answer across multiple sources and I have not found anything that answers my question specifically.

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal reproducible exemple ? Without it, that's not easy to figure what you mean with, for instnace, "default color", "the text content associate with", "the blue highlight of the text content" and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see you are using SVG-glyphs with the DevExpress [Accordion Control](https://docs.devexpress.com/WPF/118347/Controls-and-Libraries/Navigation-Controls/Accordion-Control) for WPF and trying [to customize these glyphs](https://docs.devexpress.com/WPF/119848/controls-and-libraries/navigation-controls/accordion-control/accordion-items/item-glyph-customization).

So, I suggest you start from the [Svg Images Overview](https://docs.devexpress.com/WPF/119994/common-concepts/images/svg-images-overview) help article which demonstrates the common concepts of using the SVG with DevExpress WPF controls.

TLDR, the application's [current theme](https://docs.devexpress.com/WPF/7406/common-concepts/themes) determines an SVG Image's predefined colors by default. Refer to the [Predefined Colors](https://docs.devexpress.com/WPF/120005/common-concepts/images/predefined-colors) topic for more information.

You can use **palettes** to replace predefined colors and custom colors that are not defined in DevExpress palettes. The [SVG Image Palettes](https://docs.devexpress.com/WPF/119994/common-concepts/images/svg-images-overview) article clearly describes how you can modify the colors via the palettes technique.